# How to write trigger to automatically update custom email field on my acustom account wheen email id of related contact is changed

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have written a custom account tab which fetches the data from standard account tab and i have also added custom email field to it. Below is the page which show a detail of account which is clicked on first page.

VF page :

```
<apex:page controller="recordPageCont" >  

  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
       <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!EditAccount}"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!CancelButton}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:pageBlockSection >
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.Name}"/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.AccountNumber} "/>
     <apex:param id="accountID" assignTo="{!accountID}" value="10"/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.Type} "/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.industry} "/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!objAccount.Rating} "/>

     <b>Email</b> {!objAccount.Name}@salesforce.com
    <p></p> <b>Address</b> {!objAccount.Billingstreet} {!objAccount.Billingcity}{!objAccount.Billingcountry}{!Objaccount.Billingstate}{!objAccount.BillingPostalCode}
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>

<apex:pageBlock title="Contacts Related With {!objaccount.name}"></apex:pageBlock>

<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:outputPanel id="ContactDetail">
<apex:repeat value="{! displayContacts}" var="contact">
<p><apex:inputCheckbox id="checkbox"/><apex:outputLink value="/apex/editcontact?id={!contact.id}" id="theLink">Edit</apex:outputLink> <b>Name :</b> {! contact.name} <b>Title:</b> {!contact.title} <b>Mobile</b> :{!contact.MobilePhone} <b>Email :</b>{!contact.email}</p>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>`
```

controller for above page:

```
public class recordPageCont {
public Account objAccount{get;set;}
Public string recId{get;set;}
Public string AccountID{get;set;}
Public Contact[] displayContacts {get;set;}
 public Contact cntact{get;set;}
    public recordPageCont ()
    {
        recId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
        objAccount =[SELECT Name, AccountNumber ,Type , Industry , Rating,BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry,(SELECT Name , MobilePhone,Title from Contacts) 
                     FROM account WHERE ID = :recId ];

        Account[] accts =[SELECT Name, AccountNumber ,Type , Industry , Rating, (SELECT Name , MobilePhone,Title,email from Contacts) 
                          FROM account WHERE ID = :recId ];

    Account acct = accts[0];
    if (!objAccount.Contacts.isEmpty())
    {
        displayContacts = acct.Contacts;

    }}


    Public pagereference Editaccount()
    {
        Pagereference edtaccount = new Pagereference('/apex/editaccount?id='+recid);
        edtaccount.setredirect(true);
        return edtaccount;
    }

    public pagereference cancelButton()
    {
        Pagereference cnclbutton = new Pagereference('/apex/accountdisplay');
        cnclbutton.setredirect(true);
        return cnclbutton;
    } 


}
```

Now what i want is,when an edit button is clicked on any contact and if i update a email address,then a trigger should fire which should also update the email on the account detail.

Can someone help me with this please.if you want i can paste the code of first page as well.

Comment: Can someone help..If you are not able to understand my query.please let me know.

Comment: It's hard to understand.  What I can gather is.....you have a custom email field on the Account object, whenever a contact from that account has their email address changed, you want to populate the account email address field with the contacts new email address?

Comment: Ankita, in the future, when you post code, after pasting it in, please select it and click on the preformatted text icon `{}` so it will display properly.

Comment: But you don't want to write a trigger, you just want your controller to update the email address for the contact, correct? Once you edit the contact by clicking on it, it would seem that you want to go back to this page and have it re-run the contacts query to refresh itself.

Comment: @crmprogdev - i have to write a trigger..I know it can be done by a simple controller..You see i am new to salesforce..So  i have to do it as my seniors say,,..can you help me to write a trigger?

Comment: @chrisduncombe - what i want is ..whever i change email in contacts..trigger should run and it should copy the new email address from contacts to custom email field on accounts..Did you get it now?

Comment: SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions that are real problems or errors. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you. I suggest you start with the [Apex Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/) as a resource to help you get started with your trigger or http://findsf.info/ as a search engine for code.

Comment: @crmprogdev - I have gone through the workbook..its just basics..I dont want a whole code dear.Just a hint or approach is enough

Comment: If you're updating contacts, the trigger fires on contacts, then locates the contact's parent account and assigns the value from trigger new to the custom field in accounts. Then you update the contact's parent account. That's the gist of the trigger. It also needs to test that the email address has changed before it does anything else. That should get you started.

Comment: Thank a lot..Wil post the code here if i have some problem again

Comment: I am geting the following error - No such column 'Custom_Email__c' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trigger UpdateAccountEmails on Contact (after update){  
    //extract all contact Ids for use in query
    Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
        if(trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Email != c.Email){//email has been changed
            contactIds.add(c.Id);
        }
    }

    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    for(Contact c : [SELECT Id, Account.Id, Account.Custom_Email__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contactIds]){
        //assign the new email
        c.Account.Custom_Email__c = Trigger.newMap.get(c.Id).Email;
        //extract the account into our list
        accounts.add(c.getSobject('Account'));
    }

    update accounts;
}
```

Comment: I am geting the following error -  No such column 'Custom_Email__c' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name.

Comment: You need to use the real name of your custom field...